# How to receive high Speed UDP Packets completely?

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, udp

I have a UDP Server which sends data continuously. I want to receive all the packets sent by the server.

On server side I have two threads. One thread continuously reads data from the file and puts into deque. Another thread reads data from the deque and sends to the UDP client continuously. The client code continuously receives data from the server.

I have variables to keep the count of the number of bytes sent in server code and the number of bytes received in client code.
There is huge difference between the two. The server sends about 93 MB but the client receives only 3 - 5 MB.

How can I receive all the data sent by the Server?

Please find the server and client code below.

Server Code:

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1400

typedef struct
{
    T_UCHAR buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD buf_size;
}RAWDATA_LOG;

deque<RAWDATA_LOG>  m_RawdataLog;   

void TransmitContinuous()
{
    if (m_sock_type_tcp == SOCK_UDP)
    {
        fileReadComplete=false;
        //start data transmission thread
        pWin_thread=AfxBeginThread(StartDataTransmitThread, (LPVOID) this);
        ReadFromFile();
    }   

}


void ReadFromFile()
{
    int bytesRead=0;
    m_no_of_bytes = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
    BYTE input_buf[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]={'\0'};


    GetDlgItemText(IDEBC_FILENAME,m_fileInput);


    m_InputFile=NULL;
    /*opening the file to read*/
    m_InputFile = _tfopen(m_fileInput,L"rb");
    if(m_InputFile == NULL)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Unable to open the Input file");
    }
    else
    {

        while(!feof(m_InputFile))
        {
            bytesRead=fread(input_buf,1,m_no_of_bytes,m_InputFile);

            writeRawdataToDeque(input_buf,m_no_of_bytes);
            noofBytesReadfromFile+=bytesRead;

        }
        fileReadComplete=true;
    }
}


void writeRawdataToDeque(T_UCHAR *buffer,T_S32 size)
{

    T_S32 temp_size = size;
    T_S32 size_counter = 0;
    RAWDATA_LOG temp_rawDataStruct;

    while(temp_size>0)
    {
        if(temp_size <= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            memcpy(temp_rawDataStruct.buffer,&buffer[size_counter],temp_size);
            temp_rawDataStruct.buf_size = temp_size;
            noofBytesWrittentoDeque+=temp_size;

        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(temp_rawDataStruct.buffer,&buffer[size_counter],sizeof(temp_rawDataStruct.buffer));
            temp_rawDataStruct.buf_size = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
            noofBytesWrittentoDeque+=MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
        }

        CSingleLock datalock(&m_Cs_RawDataLog);
        datalock.Lock();
        m_RawdataLog.push_back(temp_rawDataStruct);
        datalock.Unlock();


        memset(&temp_rawDataStruct,0,sizeof(temp_rawDataStruct));
        size_counter += MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
        temp_size = temp_size - MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
    }                                               
}

unsigned int StartDataTransmitThread (LPVOID param)
{

    RAWDATA_LOG temp_rawDataBuf;
    int byesWritten=0;
    CString tmpStr;

    while(1)
    {

        if(!m_RawdataLog.empty())
        {
            CSingleLock datalock(&m_Cs_RawDataLog);
            datalock.Lock();
            temp_rawDataBuf = m_RawdataLog.front();
            m_RawdataLog.pop_front();
            datalock.Unlock();

            //transmit the data through socket  
            byesWritten=WritetoClient(clientIp,clientPort,(const LPBYTE)&temp_rawDataBuf, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            noofBytesTransmitted+=byesWritten;

        }
        else
        {
            if(fileReadComplete == true)
            {

                break;
            }
        }       
    }

    return true;
}



bool CreateServer(char ipaddr[],int port)
{
    sockaddr_in ServerSockAddr;
    WORD m_wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA m_wsaData;
    int m_wsaErr;

    ServerSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.11.80");
    ServerSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerSockAddr.sin_port = htons(2011);


     m_wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);          
     m_wsaErr = WSAStartup(m_wVersionRequested, &m_wsaData);
     if (m_wsaErr != 0) 
     {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        MessageBox(L"WSAStartup failed with error:" + m_wsaErr);
        return 1;
     }

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET != sock)
    {


        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *) & ServerSockAddr, sizeof(ServerSockAddr)))
        {
            int b= GetLastError();
            closesocket( sock );
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        closesocket( sock );
        return false;
    }

    m_hComm = (HANDLE) sock;
}


int WritetoClient(char ipaddr[],int port,BYTE buf[],int len)
{

     sockaddr_in clientSockAddr;
     int res=0;


      SOCKET s = (SOCKET) m_hComm;

      clientSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.11.80");
      clientSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      clientSockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

      res = sendto( s, (const char *)buf, len, 0, (SOCKADDR  *) &clientSockAddr, sizeof(clientSockAddr));

      return res;
}
```

Client Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32")

#define BUFSIZE 1000000

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SOCKET sockfd;
    int  portno, n;
    int serverlen;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char *hostname;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int BytesReceived=0;
    int buff_size=1000000;

    WORD m_wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA m_wsaData;
    int m_wsaErr;

     m_wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);          
     m_wsaErr = WSAStartup(m_wVersionRequested, &m_wsaData);
     if (m_wsaErr != 0) 
         {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error:");
        return 1;
     }

    /* socket: create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
    {

        printf("ERROR opening socket");
    }


    else
    {
        /* build the server's Internet address */

        serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        serveraddr.sin_port = htons(2010);
        serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.11.80");



        /* send the message to the server */
        serverlen = sizeof(serveraddr);

        setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF,(char *)(&buff_size), sizeof(buff_size));

        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) & serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)))
        {
            printf("Bind Error");
            int a = GetLastError();
            printf("Error ID:%d",a);
        }
        else
        {

            printf("Reading From Server:\n");

            while(1)
            {


                n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0,(struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, &serverlen);

                if (n < 0) 
                {
                    printf("ERROR in recvfrom\n");
                    int b = GetLastError();
                    printf("Error ID:%d\n",b);
                }
                else
                {

                    BytesReceived+=n;

                    TRACE("\nTotal Bytes Received:%d\n",BytesReceived);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;



}
```

Comment: calling `inet_addr` on every block is wasteful... call it once, keep the result, and pass the numeric value not the string each time you call `WriteToClient`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues with your code.

On the server side, you are binding the server's socket to `192.168.11.80` AND you are sending packets to `192.168.11.80` as well, instead of sending them to whichever IP address is specified in the `ipaddr` parameter of the `WritetoClient()` function.

On the client side, you are `bind()`'ing the client's socket to the **server's** IP address.

This setup will only work if the client and server are running on the same machine.  It will not work between multiple machines connected through a network.

You need to bind the client to an IP address that is *local to the client's own machine*, not to the server's IP address.  And your server needs to send packets to the IP address that the client is actually bound to.

If you want to ensure that your client receives data only from the server's IP address, and not from other machines that may happen to be sending data over the same network, you can optionally `connect()` the client's socket to the server's IP address (yes, you can use `connect()` with UDP).

`bind()` is for establishing a socket's local IP address.  `connect()` is for establishing a socket's remote/peer IP address.

Since you are (potentially) not binding the client's socket correctly, and/or (potentially) not sending to the correct IP, you are likely receiving data that you are not expecting from somewhere else.  That could explain the large discrepancy you are seeing.  I would suggest having your client output the data it actually receives, so you can make sure it is receiving what you are expecting, eg:

```
n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, &serverlen);
if (n == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    int b = WSAGetLastError();
    printf("ERROR in recvfrom\nError ID:%d\n",b);
}
else
{
    BytesReceived += n;
    TRACE("\nMessage Received from %s:%hu: '%.*s'", inet_ntoa(serveraddr.sin_addr), ntohs(serveraddr.sin_port), n, buf);
    TRACE("\nTotal Bytes Received: %d\n", BytesReceived);
}
```

Comment: I hardcoded IP address and Port numbers because I am running Client and server in the same PC. I want client to receive all  packets sent by the server.